# How to access specific port in vagrant box laravel/homestead?

Tags: ports, homestead, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a node project on my vagrant laravel/homestead box.
Everything works fine, I can access the project when I go to the host define in my `/etc/hosts` :

```
192.168.10.10 project
```

But, I'm trying to build and watch my project with webpack, so I installed webpack-dev-server and I can run it :

```
http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /home/vagrant/Workspace/Kanban
404s will fallback to /index.html
[...]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

My problem is, when I try to access project:8080 with my browser, I get a loading error.

A `netstat -an | grep 8080` in the vagrant shows me that the box is listening.
I tried to forward ports using `homestead.yaml`

```
ports:
  - send: 8080
    to: 8080
    protocol: tcp
```

But with or without port forwarding, all I get is an error page.

What can I do to make my webpack watcher work ?

Comment: did you make vagrant provision?

Comment: @TraviJuu Yes I did. I just did again and retried to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I finnaly found the answer.
The problem was about not ports but the dev-server. It is configured by default to work only on the localhost. The solution was to add a rule to the configuration :

```
 devServer     : {
            [...]
            , host          : '0.0.0.0'
    }
```

Setting the host to '0.0.0.0' allows the dev-server to be accessible from anywhere, therefore, to my "real" host.
I found the explanation on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit/issues/27). Too bad that the arguments list wasn't on the official documentation.