# Trying to run npm run serve (vue-cli app) inside Laravel Homestead (VirtualBox + Vagrant)

Tags: npm, homestead, vue-cli-3

I have a `vue-cli` app, trying to run it inside Laravel Homestead.

**What I have**:

My `hosts` on host machine:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   PC
192.168.2.10 myvueapp.local
```

`hosts` inside VM:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       myvueapp.local
127.0.1.1       homestead       homestead
```

Vagrant version: 2.2.4, Homestead: v8.3.2, `vue --version`: 3.7.0

`npm run serve` executes without problems inside VM, but I get

> We're sorry but myvueapp doesn't work properly without JavaScript
>   enabled. Please enable it to continue.

as a response body from request:

```
//response headers
Request URL: https://myvueapp.local/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 192.168.2.10:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Browser page is blank.

Also there is one `favicon` request:

```
Request URL: https://myvueapp.local/%3C%=%20BASE_URL%20%%3Efavicon.ico
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 192.168.2.10:443
```

Somehow `BASE_URL` doesn't compile in `index.html`:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

My `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'myvueapp.local',
    https: true
  }
}
```

`Homestead.yaml`:

```
ip: "192.168.2.10"
#...
sites:
    - map: myvueapp.local
      to: /home/vagrant/path/to/myvueapp.local/public
#...
ports:
    - send: 8080
      to: 80
```

Port, where Vue is served (inside VM, 8080) is listening.

```
lsof -i :8080
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    3022 vagrant   22u  IPv4  31440      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .myvueapp.local;
    root "/path/to/myvueapp.local/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;



    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }
```

P. S. It runs ok when I'm serving it from my host machine.

**What I've tried**:

[change `host`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33467145/9506712)

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0', //<-- here
    https: true
  }
}
```

, didn't helped.

---

#### Edit #1

I moved a bit further, this Nginx config now allowes me to access Vue app, served inside VM, using host machine:

```
   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; #<-- this might be the output from npm run serve, without last slash
        #  App running at:
        #  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
        #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   }
```

But there is still a problem: hot-reload doesn't work.

Comment: Any luck on this? I've hit the same wall and can't get past it

Comment: @AndrewFox nope, I didn't find a way out